# Can i install ubuntu touch on lenovo tab with ARMv7 processor

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My lenovo A1000 tablet runs the ARM cortex A9 processor based on the ARMv7 architecture,can i install ubuntu touch on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Ubuntu touch on Lenovo Tab.

Here are the supported devices:

```
http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/
```

How to install on some devices:

```
http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/
```

Portings are coming soon, your best chance will be someone have the device and he did effort to port your device.

On the site they say: A new porting guide will be written shortly and be availble at Touch/Porting

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting